# How to list all functions in a namespace?

Tags: c++

Is that possible to list all functions in a namespace in C++? Just like reflection in C#.

Comment: No.  Not least because namespaces are open; other headers could add to a namespace, so simply looking at a single header that declares elements of a namespace is not sufficient to tell you.

Comment: No. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's something that an IDE can do for you (e.g. Visual Studio), but it's for the programmer and not for the code itself.

Comment: attempting to create reflection in C++ will *probably* break the "zero overhead principle" the language adopts

Answer (score 8):

There's no built in reflection in C++ (for namespaces or even classes).

Comment: Well you have minimal type info using typeid. But no info on members though.